# How to set DevExpress MVC GridView Edit button hidden for some certain fields?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, devexpress

I have a DevExpress MVC GridView in my project, I want to hide DevExpress MVC GridView Edit button for some certain fields. any idea?

Here is my View Code.

```
@Html.DevExpress().GridView(settings =>
{
    settings.Name = "GridView";
    settings.CallbackRouteValues = new { Controller = "Home", Action =   "GridViewPartial" };

    settings.SettingsEditing.AddNewRowRouteValues = new { Controller = "Home", Action = "GridViewPartialAddNew" };
    settings.SettingsEditing.UpdateRowRouteValues = new { Controller = "Home", Action = "GridViewPartialUpdate" };
    settings.SettingsEditing.DeleteRowRouteValues = new { Controller = "Home", Action = "GridViewPartialDelete" };
    settings.SettingsEditing.Mode = GridViewEditingMode.EditFormAndDisplayRow;
    settings.SettingsBehavior.ConfirmDelete = true;

    settings.CommandColumn.Visible = true;
    settings.CommandColumn.NewButton.Visible = true;
    settings.CommandColumn.DeleteButton.Visible = true;
    settings.CommandColumn.EditButton.Visible = true;

    settings.KeyFieldName = "FirstCmOutputId";

    settings.SettingsPager.Visible = true;
    settings.Settings.ShowGroupPanel = true;
    settings.Settings.ShowFilterRow = true;
    settings.SettingsBehavior.AllowSelectByRowClick = true;


    settings.SettingsDetail.AllowOnlyOneMasterRowExpanded = true;
    settings.SettingsDetail.ShowDetailRow = true;

    settings.Columns.Add("Name");
    settings.Columns.Add("Intervention");
    settings.Columns.Add("Indicator");
    settings.Columns.Add("UseOfOutput");
    settings.Columns.Add("UserOfOutput");
    settings.Columns.Add("PlanningFrom");
    settings.Columns.Add("PlanningTo");
    settings.Columns.Add("DateOfPlanning");
    settings.Columns.Add("City");

    settings.SetDetailRowTemplateContent(c => {
            Html.RenderAction("GridView1Partial", new { OutputID =  DataBinder.Eval(c.DataItem, "FirstCmOutputId") });
        });
}).Bind(Model).GetHtml()
```

In above View code the Edit button is enable for all the fields but i need to disable the Edit button for some certain fields. Any help would be appreciated.

Regards

Comment: post code..you can do this using jquery..

Comment: Gimme some more info? Thanks

Comment: on what condition you want to hide and which column?

Comment: Why don't you contact DevExpress support directly?

Comment: Wanted to get a fast reply that's why. I already submitted a ticket in DevExpress too.

Answer (score 1):

This is for people that will search the same thing in the future.
You can easily control the state of a command button for a given row

```
settings.CommandButtonInitialize = (sender, e) =>
    {
        if (e.VisibleIndex == -1) return;
        if (e.ButtonType == ColumnCommandButtonType.Edit)
        {
            e.Column.Visible = (bool)((MVCxGridView)sender).GetRowValues(e.VisibleIndex, "MyBoolProperty");
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an update with the latest Devexpress
use 
e.visible instead of e.Column.Visible